# Split one request across multiple tomcat servers to fetch data from Cassandra DB

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cassandra

We have 6 tomcat servers running in environment and my application war is deployed on each server. In current scenario, i am fetching required data from cassandra using pagination. Suppose there are 10,000 records in DB, it will fetch 1-1000 first then next set of data. Important point is it is utilizing only one tomcat server since this is one request due to which wait time is more.

Now, i want to split this request across 6 different tomcat servers like 1st tomcat will fetch 1-1000 rows then 2nd from 1001-2000 and so on. Then aggregate all responses to single response. So, is there any way in Camel using spring DSL to spilt single route request across multiple tomcat servers, in this way i can utilize all servers to boost performance. Appreciate your valuable inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to page through rows within a single partition at different offsets at a time.  [The protocol spec](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/native_protocol_v3.spec#L888-L919) defines a paging state that is returned from each query.  That paging state is then used to retrieve the next page of rows.  The paging state is considered internal and should not be manipulated.  In java-driver 2.0.10/2.1.6 there is a mechanism to set the paging state on a statement ([JAVA-550](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-550)), but it is very strict in that the paging state must be derived from the original query, so you can keep that state for later and continue the query at another time.

However, if you are making range queries (which I suspect since you have many rows), one option is to consider is the [datastax spark connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) which has a mechanism for breaking apart range queries into token ranges and delegating the queries by token range into tasks that are submitted to spark workers.   If you could somehow run a spark worker within each of your tomcat instances, that could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [splitter EIP](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) in combination with an aggregation strategy. The latter can be used to assemble the replies from the sub-messages, into a single outgoing message from the Splitter. You may also want to check out this [Camel Cassandra](https://github.com/joef551/camel-cql) component, as it is quite flexible and robust.